# Xamarin.forms How to draw route between two pins?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` nuget package. This is my code:

```
                var location = Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                if (location == null)
                {
                    location = Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(new GeolocationRequest
                    {

                        DesiredAccuracy = GeolocationAccuracy.Medium,
                        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                    }); ;

                }

                map.MoveToRegion(
                  MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(location.Result.Latitude, location.Result.Longitude), Distance.BetweenPositions(new Position(location.Result.Latitude, location.Result.Longitude), new Position(Double.Parse(latit), Double.Parse(longi)))));
                map.MapType = MapType.Street;
                Pin pinUserLocation = new Pin
                {
                    Label = "Your Location",
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(location.Result.Latitude, location.Result.Longitude)
                };
                map.Pins.Add(pinUserLocation);
                Pin pinPharmacyLocation = new Pin
                {
                    Label = "Your Destination",
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Double.Parse(latit), Double.Parse(longi))
                };
                map.Pins.Add(pinPharmacyLocation);

                Polyline polyline = new Polyline
                {
                    StrokeColor = Color.FromHex("#07987f"),
                    StrokeWidth = 10,
                    Geopath =
                    {
                    new Position(location.Result.Latitude, location.Result.Longitude),
                    new Position(Double.Parse(latit), Double.Parse(longi))
                    }
                    };

                // add the polyline to the map's MapElements collection
                map.MapElements.Add(polyline);
```

With this code it shows me polyline but i need a route from user location to destination. I cant find in the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/ . Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Nope, xamarin forms map control cannot show the route, you could change other nuget plugin to achieve it. such as `TK.CustomMap`, this nuget package support it. http://torbenk.github.io/TK.CustomMap/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT can i get this from the GoogleMaps APi and append to the map?

Comment: Do you mean use Google Directions API? to get the postion data, then use `polyline` to draw it? If so, it could be achieved.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT but with that will draw again polyline not a root ?

Comment: I do not know about not a root, do you mean cover to other polyline?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT sorry miss spell  i mean route

Comment: GoogleMaps APi not only contains postion data, but also contians direction information(such as direction, distance to destination). If you just want to draw a polyline between two pins, you can use xamarin.froms.map plugin, If you want to achieve the navigation, native  xamarin.froms.map plugin cannot achieve it.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT how to achive route between two  pins? Some article, plugin?

Comment: You can use `TK.CustomMap` to achieve route, here is simple code about router:https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/Development/Source/Samples/Sample/TK.CustomMap.Sample/ViewModels/AddRouteViewModel.cs